# Project Euler #10 Java not working

Tags: java, project

The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.

Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

```
            public class Problem10
            {
                public static void main(String[] args)
                {
                    int sum = 17;
                    for(long i=11; i<2000000; i+=2)
                    {
                        if(isPrime(i)) sum += i;
                    }
                    System.out.println(sum);    

                }

                public static boolean isPrime(long n)
                {
                    if(n==2) return true;
                    if(n%2 == 0) return false;
                    for(long i=3; i<= Math.sqrt(n); i+=2)
                    {
                        if(n%i == 0) return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

I don't see what is wrong with this. It keeps printing 1179908154 which is incorrect.

Comment: What is the correct result?

Comment: You define i as a long, but not the sum, @Mureinik 142913828922.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be something simple like that

Answer (score 3):

Your `sum` is an `int`, but integer overflow is occurring.  If you change the datatype to `long`, then the answer changes to `142913828922`, which is longer than the maximum possible `int`.  [That appears to be the correct answer.](http://code.jasonbhill.com/sage/project-euler-problem-10/)